# Prevent window.open() from refreshing the window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I hope you are great!
May someone shed a light on this one

**Use case**

1. Page A opens page B with window.open()
2. Refresh page A and try to focus page B with window.open() again.

**Code**

```js
if (!window.memwin || window.memwin.closed) {
    window.memwin = window.open(URL, "windowName", "",true)
}
window.memwin.focus();
```

**Problem**

The focus on page B happens but the page is reloaded. Is there any method to overcome this issue?
I want the page B to be focused without been reloaded.

*(If page A is not reloaded then focus to page B with window.open() will not reload the page B)

Comment: I'd consider it a security issue if any window could access every other window after beeing detached.

Comment: @DanielW. Indeed but is there anything I can do to get that reference to the window object.

Comment: I think the only possible way is if you put the [return value of `window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) into the local storage instead of the current window instance (because that gets destroyed on reloading). It may not work due to serialization but it's worth a try. A better and more modern approach would be to simply not use external windows but put the content in one window and work with ajax and appropriate div containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a way to solve this.

- In a cookie I save the state of the window(open/closed)
- Use this to create the window

```js
window.open(URL, "windowName", "",true)
```

- Use this to focus back to the window

```js
window.open('', "windowName", "",true)
```

By doing that user will be able to focus page B from everywhere. The only thing that we need to know is the windowName and if that is still opened or closed